# How to bring such details on face and dull cyan color grading like in this image?

Tags: post-processing, color-management, effect

I have sufficient experience in Photoshop and prefer it over Lightroom. I want to know the directions to achieve these specialties of the image below:

1. Facial details in wrinkles and hair.
2. *Dull* cyan-like color all over the image without giving a feel of *sheet* of coloured paper over it.
3. Overall dull look in terms of light with good exposure, less contrast but so less haze. These are conflicting properties.
4. Color of water.
5. I think sky can be made so by dehazing, desaturating and reducing blacks.

I might be wrong in some of my assessments here, if so please correct me!

[image: Image by Paolo Piantadosi on Behance]

Image by Paolo Piantadosi on [Behance: The old man and the sea](https://www.behance.net/gallery/80669743/THE-OLD-MAN-AND-THE-SEA)

Comment: 1) possibly [this](https://xenedis.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/calvin-hollywoods-freaky-detail/)

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you. 1) Sorted out "Freaky amazing detail" by Calving Hollywood https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZV9u0Wu8L0M or a bit of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1GPbuv0IwM if we need a pop-out. 
Looking forward to the other 5

Comment: If you google "Bleach bypass look" for your particular flavor of post processing app, you'll be well on your way.

Comment: @MichaelC yes thank you! That was enough for third part. I think I can incorporate the same in xenoid's method while I am popping the details out.

Comment: Dunno....looks to me like not only was cyan added to the image, but cyanide to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolate person, apply tone mapping to him only or dodge and burn shadows and highlights by hand.

Add cyan to entire image, this also adjusts the water/sky color.

That is the basic adjustments that I see.  I don't think the background was selected and processed separately.  I think most of the processing was done on the isolated subject.

Note:  Without the original to judge by, it is not possible to give specific answers.